# New animation after setState - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I don't find the answer to my problem for my react native app.

If you have an idea how to achieve that, that would be great :)

**What I'm trying to do:**

In a page, when I press somewhere, I want to display an animation (for example a square apparition) on the press position.

**What I have achieved:**
When I click, a square is display with an animation on the right position.
But when i click somewhere else, The position of the square changes but the animation doesn't restart.

**What I have tried:**

To do the animation, I place a < View/> (with position: 'absolute') on the press position.

This < View/> is embeded in a component that I call 1 time in my App render:

```
<ClickAnimation x={item.x} y={item.y}/>
```

where item.x and item.y are are the coordinate.

This is the code of my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Animated, View} from 'react-native';

export default class ClickAnimation extends React.Component {
  state = {
    scaleAnim: new Animated.Value(0)
  };
  componentWillMount() {
    Animated
      .timing(this.state.scaleAnim, {
      toValue: 2,
      duration: 500
    })
      .start();
  }
  componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.x != this.props.x && nextProps.y != this.props.y) {
      this.setState({
        scaleAnim: new Animated.Value(0)
      })
    }
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("componentDidUpdate",this.state.scaleAnim)
    Animated
      .timing(this.state.scaleAnim, {
      toValue: 2,
      duration: 500
    })
      .start();
  }
  render() {
    return (<Animated.View
      style={{
      position: "absolute",
      top: this.props.y,
      left: this.props.x,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      backgroundColor: "red",
      transform: [
        {
          scaleY: this.state.scaleAnim
        }, {
          scaleX: this.state.scaleAnim
        }, {
          translateX: -25
        }, {
          translateY: -25
        }
      ]
    }}/>);
  }
}
```

The console.log in componentDidUpdate give me for each click 2 logs:

{_children: Array(2), _value: 2, ..., _animation: null…}

{_children: Array(2), _value: 0,..., _animation: null…}

I really don't know what to do next.

PS: In NativeScript, that was more easy. I had just to add the new component to the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

This come with this issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6278

I had seen it and this is why I wrote first 0,001. But 0,001 is still to little. With 0,01 it works great.

**So the answer is:**

Just replace 0 by 0.01 because it was too little.

Answer (score 0):

According to React docs you cannot this.setState() inside componentWillUpdate(),if you need to update state in response to a prop change, use componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) instead.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Read the above link for more details on that and check its caveats.
I hope this is what is causing the problem

Comment: I have tried with componentWillReceiveProps but that doesn't change the result. A console.log in componentWillReceiveProps shows me that the state get correctly the data.

Comment: Just try increasing the duration from 500 to 5000 ms and check whats happening

Comment: Endeed, that's working. The second click animation is showing. But The animation doesn't work great. There is no transition. I don't know if this is a problem with  EXPO or a problem with de code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that EXPO XDE make the application too slow and this is why the animation part doesn't work properly.